# Connection to ais.ajou.uz timed out, requests http site scraping

Tags: python, http, python-requests, connection, screen-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getTimetable(group):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        link = 'http://ais.ajou.uz/uz/sign-in/login'
        s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'
        res = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')   
        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}         
        payload['LoginForm[username]'] = f"202190336"
        payload['LoginForm[password]'] = f"202190336"
        s.post(link,data=payload)
        groups = ['A-101', 'A-102', 'E-101', 'E-102', 'E-104', 'E-103', 'E-105', 'E- 
        106', 'A-103', 'A-104', 'A-105', 'A-106', 'C-101', 'C-102', 'C-103', 'C-104', 
        'C-105', 'C-106', 'A-201', 'A-202', 'A-203', 'A-204', 'A-205', 'A-206', 'C- 
        201', 'C-202', 'C-203', 'C-204', 'C-205', 'C-206', 'E-201', 'E-202', 'E-203', 
        'E-204', 'E-205', 'E-206']
        index = groups.index(f"{group}")
        res = s.get(f"http://ais.ajou.uz/uz/site/students-time-table?id=4&groupId= 
        {index+1}") 
        return res

getTimetable("E-204")
```

If I run this code, I got this :

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ais.ajou.uz', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /uz/sign-in/login (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2b55078814e0>, 'Connection to ais.ajou.uz timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
```

The code works when I run locally, but in the server(cPanel), it didn't work, I fed up with this issue, I hope if someone can help me :)

Comment: 80 port open in server?

Comment: How do I know open or not?

Comment: But in heroku server it worked, as you said I think 80 port is closed maybe

Comment: use `telnet` or `nmap`

Comment: could you pls answer more clearly, what is telnet or nmap

Comment: OS utilities, usage telnet - telnet yorserver.domain 80, nmap - nmap yorserver.domain , it show every opened port. Just give ur server address and I scan it

Comment: `https://oik-group.uz/aut_timetable_bot` its my telegram bots link

Comment: Connection to oik-group.uz:80 - ok. 
The server itself has an open port, but I don’t know how containers with bots and firewalls are distributed inside. You'd better contact the hosting support and clarify this issue.

Comment: ok I will try it